# Do all primes occur in some sequence associated with the Collatz conjecture?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

Let $f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$

For an arbitrary prime $p$ are there some start value $x_0$ such that $p = x_k$ for some $k > 0$ in the sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$?

I was confused. What I really wondered, turns out to be if all primes $> 3$ could be written as $3n + 1$ with $n$ odd, which is also trivially true. Or? No! I'll try again without Collatz.

---

Define $f(p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k}) = p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$, where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. Is any prime $> 3$ in the image of the function 
$g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, defined by $g(n) = f(3f(n) + 1)$.

I see now that all odd numbers not divisible by $3$ are in the image.

Comment: Start with $2p$, or $2^kp$.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $3n+1$ is even. So you can never write a prime as $3n+1$ with $n \in 2 \mathbb{N}+1$.

Comment: You have observed an important property of Collatz, namely that the function maps a path from every multiple of $3$ to a $\{2^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ - assuming it is true!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just take $x_0=2p$ and then $x_1=p$.